# How does the FrameworkElement.Loaded event work with virtualization?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml

Each `FrameworkElement` has a `Loaded` event that fires when...

> the tree is not only built and initialized, but layout has run on it,
>   data has been bound, it's connected to a rendering surface (window),
>   and you're on the verge of being rendered.  When we reach that point,
>   we canvas the tree by broadcasting the Loaded event, starting at the
>   root.  This event corresponds to the IsLoaded property.

What is the expected behaviour for the tree segment/elements when they are virtualized off screen, appear on screen, run off screen again and again reappear later?

I would expect the event not to fire twice, so not when appearing on screen again, but the timing of the first firing is not clear to me.

Luke

Comment: As far as I know, the event `Framework.Loaded` will be fire every time when you will scroll through the list. For example - `ListBox`. (You can really see the different virtualization options, such as "cycle", etc). I tried to apply the animation to load a new element in `ListBox`, but the event was fired every time you scroll. This event It should be used for *static* controls that are rendered only once, such as when the program starts.

Comment: Create a handler for the Loaded event and see for yourself when it fires.

Comment: @Blam - I did, it fires for all items up front, except for 2 items that load on scroll left. When I added more items, it did the same thing. So I'd prefer a citation or a MSFT controls team member or perhaps another developer who's just good at writing in a plausible and convincing manner :)

Comment: No matter how many items you load it fires for all but 2 items.  You list several platforms.  Which did you test on?   Please post your test code.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev - Please leave a proper answer, since you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting a comment in answer: As far as I know, the event `FrameworkElement.Loaded` will be fire every time when you will scroll through the list. For example - `ListBox`.
I tried to apply the animation to load a new element in `ListBox`, but the event was fired every time you scroll. It was all so, because:

But the default setting [`ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx) is set to `true`, this means that when you scroll through each item is created newly. This is done to improve the loading of large lists a large number of elements. If it is set to `false`, then once all the elements are loaded into memory, which can affect performance if many elements. And the event `FrameworkElement.Loaded` will fire only once (at least it should be, the test for a small `ListBox`).

Quote from good source about `CanContentScroll`:

> ScrollViewer currently allows two scrolling modes: smooth pixel-by-pixel scrolling (CanContentScroll = false) or discrete item-by-item scrolling (CanContentScroll = true). Currently WPF supports UI virtualization only when scrolling by item. Pixel-based scrolling is also called “physical scrolling” and item-based scrolling is also called “logical scrolling”.

Even in the case of property `Visibility`, that is:

```
Visibility.Collapsed -> Visibility.Visible
```

The event `FrameworkElement.Loaded` called only once the first conversion visibility. If you later change the visibility property, the event will not fire.

I think, this event It should be used for *static* controls that are rendered only *once*, such as when the program starts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is rather odd, possibly a threading issue is stopping my debugger writing output (?) but an attached property I use to apply a random jilt to elements fires again and again when scrolling, so the loaded event is called every time.

Anatoliy answered in the comments, so I'll ask him to post an answer and collect his prize.